# Symfony2 translation

Tags: symfony, translation

According to the current [Translation Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html), Symfony2 looks for message files (i.e. translations) in the following locations:

```
the <kernel root directory>/Resources/translations directory;
the <kernel root directory>/Resources/<bundle name>/translations directory;
the Resources/translations/ directory of the bundle.
```

Is there any way to force Symfony2 to look into

```
the <kernel root directory>/Resources/translations/mydirectory directory;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own translation loader `Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\LoaderInterface` and tag it with `translation.loader`.

Your translator have to implement `loadMessages($directory, MessageCatalogue $catalogue)` method.

You can implement it as 
`$this->symfonyLoader->loadMessages($directory."/subdir",  $catalogue);`

You can pass `$this->symfonyLoader` using DI container